# How to get Facebook OAuth Authorization code in Android

Tags: android, facebook, oauth

I am creating an android app and using Google and Facebook Login for user authentication using OAuth tokens. I am planning to get the authorization code on my app and send it securely to my backend server where i will request for the access token. I am able to do this for Google. But I am unable to find code/lib/documentation to get the authorization code from Facebook in my app. Can someone point me to code or any documentation for the same ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this git project by facebook. It has sample source code and several examples explained. [facebook-android-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. But it doesnt have what I am looking for.